# How can i generate listView base on date range?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How can i manage to do a listview base on range of dates any idea?

[image: generate ListView]

Is its possible to do this thing?

Comment: how did you generate this snapshots?

Comment: @Jesson: Any specific reason you want to go for listView. Why not Datagrid?

Comment: @David: i just wrote it on xaml..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="myView">
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In YourForm.cs

```
private void CreateColumns()
{
    var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 05, 07);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2013, 05, 17);

    //// Ensure that startDate < endDate, no validation in this example.

    var tmp = startDate;
    while (tmp <= endDate)
    {
        GridViewColumn gc = new GridViewColumn();
        gc.Header = tmp.ToShortDateString();
        gc.Width = 100;
        this.myView.Columns.Add(gc);
        tmp = tmp.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i bind this on my sqlite data?